# pg_qualstats index recommendation on readonly replica

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I use
[pg_qualstats](https://powa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/stats_extensions/pg_qualstats.html)

And get nise suggested index recommendation.
For read only replica I have another profile of queries.

Is it possible to get suggested index recommendation based on queries on replica ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'd have to create the indexes on the primary. Note that even if you don't use the indexes on the primary, still every data modification has to update them, which makes these operations slower.